# Parallel processing in rstudio using PSOCK

Tags: r, postgresql, foreach, doparallel

I need help in parallel processing in R, currently the sequential loop takes a lot of time to execute as the data is huge, the function refers multiple tables from sql database and create 3 dataframe in each loop , in each sequence the data get appended in the 3 dataframe. is it possible to do parallel processing ?

Here is the sample code

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

date <- read.csv("date_split_sample.csv")
head(date)
start_date end_date
01-Jan-2021 30-jan-2021
01-Feb-2021 28-Feb-2021
........
```

i have to run each loop for the start & end date mentioned in above table

```
numcores <- detectcores()
cl <- makecluster(numcores,type="PSOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach (i=1:nrow(date),.combine='rbind') %dopar%{
a <- db.q("select * from abcd where date between start_date[i] and end_date[i] )
b <- db.q("select * from efgh where date between start_date[i] and end_date[i] )
c <- db.q("select * from ijkl where date between start_date[i] and end_date[i] )

#some process using above dataframe and 3 dataframe created in each loop
output1
output2
output3
}
```

i want these 3 datafame in such a way that in each loop data gets appended

I donot know how to create multiple dataframe & append the records of each loop and how to see the appended 3 dataframe

Comment: I think the fastest approach would be to use the package `data.table`. Instead of using `read.csv()`, use `data.table::fread()`. To subset for your date range, use `data.table::dataToFilter[dateColumn %between% c("2021-08-01", "2021-08-11")]`. Parallel processing is great, but if the functions you use have to be written to support that processing. The library data.table is wicked fast, compared to many other elements in R.

Comment: Thanks for replying, the above code is just an example , I have to run the loop for different dates and then do many different joins to arrive at the results, also I have to fetch data from a database, so can data.table can be used for that???

Comment: Yes, based on the list of tasks you've given, the `data.table` package is capable. You could also read [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.11144.pdf) to learn more about parallel processing in R.